# confirmation form step2.html Django

Tags: django

What is the best way to show confirmation on step2.html in Django?

#### `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
```

#### `views.py`:

```
from django.views.generic import FormView
from .forms import ContactForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
def step1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ContactForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                    #save and cleared_form
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/step2/')
    else:
            form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'step1.html', {'form': form})
def step2(request):
    ctx = { 'Test_1': 'email@email.com'}
    return render(request, 'step2.html', ctx)
```

#### `step2.html`:

```
{{Test_1}}
```

On step 2 I want to show fields submitted on step 1, how to achieve that?

Comment: You don't seem to have asked a question.

Comment: In step2.html show the fields included in the form step1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Good solution will be to show `step2.html` in `step1` view when valid form is submitted, instead of redirecting user to step2. That way you will have access to your form data in view and template.

When submitting confirmation, values from step 1 can be passed by hidden fields or saved into session storage.

Example:

```
def step1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ctx = {'contact_data': form.cleaned_data}
            return render(request, 'step2.html', ctx)
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'step1.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Its work.          If I would like to separately name ?  ctx = {'contact_data_name': ???????? } or ctx = {'form_name' : ???????}

Comment: Please use proper language because I didn't understand a word from your comment...

Comment: OK  I'll try. I have form (name,email,message).  I would check 'name' before transferring to ctx.  For example if  'contact_data.name' = 'Pio'  'contact_data.name' = ' something'.   Then ctx = {'contact_data': form.cleaned_data}

Answer (score 1):

You can save whole form data (cleaned_data) into session storage before redirection in step 1. That way you will be able to retrieve that data in step 2. Example:

```
def step1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #save and cleared_form
            request.session.contact_form = form.cleaned_data
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/step2/')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'step1.html', {'form': form})
def step2(request):
    contact_data = request.session.get('contact_form', None)

    if contact_data is None:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/step1/')
        # someone is entering step 2 directly, without submitted form in step 1, we should redirect him back to step 1.

    ctx = {'contact_data': contact_data}
    return render(request, 'step2.html', ctx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Form wizard](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/). It will handle for you passing submitted data between steps (using cookies or session). All you need to do is: create 2 views, one with proper form, one with just some confirmation button and in template for step 2 retrieve all data from step 1.